# How to get id from route using vue with laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have an overview section, when my details button is clicked for an item in the overview I want to display my database items from that item on another page.

**How can I get the id from my route to make a get request to that id in vue?**

**overview component**

```
<a class="button float-right" @click="getAccount(account.id)"/>

// in my methods

getAccount(id) {
  window.location.href = '/accounts/' + id;
}
```

**My laravel route**

```
Route::get('/accounts/{account}', 'PageController@details')->name('details.index');
```

I know I can use route model binding for this but would like to keep it in a vue component

**Controller**

```
public function details() 
{
   return view('layouts.details');
}
```

**Details component**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            account : {
                title: null,
                information: null,
                cb: null,
                qp: null,
                price: null,
                skills: [],
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchAccount();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchAccount() {
            // make axios request to the id to get account information
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also not sure what the best approach for this would be. Should I even work with laravel web routes for this page? (If I don't, I still need to inherit the layouts.app file, not sure how that would be done without using the routes)

Any tips?

Comment: Why you dont use id property in you account object in vue componenect. If you use account objecte there, you can use this obejct when you need to redirect. Other, in some plase you are calling detailis componente, you can use a prop too for example account_id or maybe directly send account object instead. Eg. <details :account="{ ur account json object }" .... />